# Java - Split a String?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

My String is ,

```
   String myString = "Hello   Boom,  Ho3w are || You ? Are  ^  you ," fr45ee   now ?";
```

I tried the below to split the string as ,

**"Hello,Boom,Ho3w,are,You,Are,you,fr45ee,now"** - where **comma** indicates the separation of String to String array. My code is

```
  String[] temp = data.split("\\s+\\^,?\"'\\|+");
```

But it is no working . Hope You people helps.Thanks.

Comment: `myString` is not the correct string. you need to escape the `"` character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example won't compile as you have an unescaped double quote in your `myString` variable.

However, assuming it **is** escaped...

```
//                                                               | escaped " here
String myString = "Hello   Boom,  Ho3w are || You ? Are  ^  you ,\" fr45ee   now ?";
//                 | printing array
//                 |               | splitting "myString"...
//                 |               |               | on 1 or more non-word 
//                 |               |               | characters
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myString.split("\\W+")));
```

**Output**

```
[Hello, Boom, Ho3w, are, You, Are, you, fr45ee, now]
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe this should work:

```
String myString = "Hello   Boom,  Ho3w are || You ? Are  ^  you ,\" fr45ee   now ?";
String[] arr = myString.split("\\W+");
//=> [Hello, Boom, Ho3w, are, You, Are, you, fr45ee, now]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you literally only trying to split on the characters in your original regex, you should factor out the `+` and put everything into a character class.

```
public class Split {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myString = "Hello   Boom,  Ho3w are || You ? Are  ^  you ,\" fr45ee   now ?";
        String[] temp = myString.split("[\\s\\^,?\"'\\|]+");
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
            System.out.println(temp[i]); 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
Boom
Ho3w
are
You
Are
you
fr45ee
now
```